# Работа с Random в C#

Tags: c#, случайные-числа

Помогите пожалуйста сделать движение объекта по полю хаотичным, а также задать их начальное положение не в левом верхнем углу. Сейчас все 4 объекта находятся в левом вернем углу и там двигаются по окружности радиусом 5.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Game_of_life
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
    public Bitmap entityElement1 = Resource1.entity,
                  entityElement2 = Resource1.entity,
                  entityElement3 = Resource1.entity,
                  entityElement4 = Resource1.entity;
    int x1;
    int y1;
    int x2;
    int y2;
    int x3;
    int y3;
    int x4;
    int y4;


    private void timer2_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Random randomInterval = new Random();
        timer2.Interval = randomInterval.Next(20, 21);
        x1 = randomInterval.Next(-5, 5);
        y1 = randomInterval.Next(-5, 5);
        x2 = randomInterval.Next(-5, 5);
        y2 = randomInterval.Next(-5, 5);
        x3 = randomInterval.Next(-5, 5);
        y3 = randomInterval.Next(-5, 5);
        x4 = randomInterval.Next(-5, 5);
        y4 = randomInterval.Next(-5, 5);

    }

    private void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Refresh();
    }

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        SetStyle(ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer | ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint | ControlStyles.UserPaint, true); 

        UpdateStyles();
    }

    private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        Graphics graphica = e.Graphics;
        graphica.DrawImage(entityElement1, new Rectangle(x1, y1, 5, 5));
        graphica.DrawImage(entityElement2, new Rectangle(x2, y2, 5, 5));
        graphica.DrawImage(entityElement3, new Rectangle(x3, y3, 5, 5));
        graphica.DrawImage(entityElement4, new Rectangle(x4, y4, 5, 5));
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Есть такая штука, думая все ее делали когда начинали программировать на C#(Windows Forms) это убегающая кнопка, думаю это то что вам надо) http://www.cyberforum.ru/windows-forms/thread179981.html

Comment: А в чем проблема? Вы нашли чужой код, и просите нас переделать его?

Comment: `Random randomInterval = new Random();` - эту строку уберите из метода и сделайте статическим приватным полем класса.

Comment: @Bulson не помогло

Comment: не совсем, у меня сейчас есть 4 объекта которые должны перемещаться рандомно по полю с шагом 5 без зависимости от курсора, кнопки и тд, а они как-то не очень рандомно, забились в левый верхний угол и там крутятся

Comment: `x1 = randomInterval.Next(-5, 5);` ===> `x1 += randomInterval.Next(-5, 5);` ?

Comment: @tym32167 , спасибо, стало получше, но уже решил пойти другим путем, вопрос больше не актуален.

Comment: Решил пойти другим путем, вопрос больше не актуален.